# @ConversationScoped bean reconstructed during page-to-page navigation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation, cdi, conversation-scope

I just found a strange behavior when I change from one page to another.

I'm using CDI, Jsf 2.2 API 2.2.8, Omnifaces 2.2, Primefaces 5.2, wildfly 8.2.

Most of the controllers and pages work as expected, but some of them, when I access the page, call the method @PostConstruct, which starts the conversation, then, when I leave the page, the @PostConstruct is called again. I realized that something in page.xhtml is the cause, so I started to look for it. But is a strange behaviour anyway.

Following my code and some examples:

Controller which uses abstract class methos like beginconversation() and list()

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class PromptConfigurationController extends BaseController<PromptConfiguration> implements Serializable {

    public PromptConfigurationController() {
        super(PromptConfiguration.class);

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list();
        loadFilters();
    }

}
```

Abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseController<T extends BaseEntity> {
  public void list() {
        logger.info("list()");

        items = getService().findAll(entityClass);
        item = null;
        beginConversation();
    }

    protected void beginConversation() {
        logger.info("beginConversation()");

        if (conversation != null && conversation.isTransient()) {
            conversation.begin();
            conversation.setTimeout(CONVERSATION_TIMEOUT);
            logger.info("Conversation iniciada: " + conversation.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

some xhtml pages which I found problem and the solution (when I found) was:

Error:

```
  <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{webChatSearchController.dateHelper.getLocalizedDatePattern()}" />
```

The method above just return a pattern.

Working

```
<f:convertDateTime dateStyle="dd/MM/yyyy" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

---

Error:

```
<p:commandButton id="commandButton-active" action="#{satisfactionSurveyController.changeQuestionStatus(true)}" update="form-content" binding="#{satisfactionSurveyController.activeButton}" value="#{bundle['common.active.3.message']}">
```

Working:

```
<p:commandButton id="commandButton-active" action="#{satisfactionSurveyController.changeQuestionStatus(true)}" update="form-content"  value="#{bundle['common.active.3.message']}" disabled="#{satisfactionSurveyController.disableActiveButton}">
```

The problem was just the "binding".

---

Error:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable-group-email" var="emailMonitor" value="#{emailMonitorController.listEmailGroup}" selectionMode="single"   rowKey="#{emailMonitor}" filteredValue="#{emailMonitorController.listEmailGroupFiltered}">
```

Working:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable-group-email" var="emailMonitor" value="#{emailMonitorController.listEmailGroup}" selectionMode="single"   rowKey="#{emailMonitor}" >
```

Just removing 'filteredValue' started working. But without it, I can't use the filter properties.

---

The navigation is made by a menu of primefaces, all the pages are the same logic:

```
<p:menuitem id="satisfactionSurvey" action="#{satisfactionSurveyController.listPage}" value="#{bundle[satisfactionSurvey.message']}"  ajax="false" immediate="true">
                            <f:param name="nocid" value="true" />
                        </p:menuitem>
```

and the Method:

```
public String listPage() {        
        return baseViewPath + "/list.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if in all cases the conversation id is present in the call to the server?

Comment: This answers your XY-problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15521451

Comment: @BalusC: for the navigation yes, but also for the filtering? Or do I miss something?

Comment: Yes it is, the conversation id is always present. @Kukeltje.

Comment: @BalusC, so, the face-redirect is causing the behaviour? But, isn't it strange that just changing some components it starts to work as expected?

Comment: @BalusC I used 'outcome' and worked, no more postconstruct called after navigation. This behaviour shouldn't happen with all pages navigation? because it happens just with a few.